# ElasticSearch 2.1.0 - Deep 'children' aggregation with 'sum' metric returning empty results

Tags: elasticsearch, parent-child, aggregation

I have a hierarchy of document types two levels deep. The documents are related by [parent-child relationships](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-parent-field.html) as follows: *category* > *sub_category* > *item* i.e. each *sub_category* has a `_parent` field referring to a *category* id, and each *item* has a `_parent` field referring to a *sub_category* id.

Each *item* has a `price` field. Given a query for categories, which includes conditions for sub-categories and items, I want to calculate a total price for each *sub_category*.

My query looks something like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "has_child": {
            "child_type": "sub_category",
            "query": {
                "has_child": {
                    "child_type": "item",
                    "query": {
                        "range": {
                            "price": {
                                "gte": 100,
                                "lte": 150
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My aggregation to calculate the price for each sub-category looks like this:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "categories": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "id"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "sub_categories": {
                    "children": {
                        "type": "sub_category"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "sub_category_ids": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "id"
                            },
                            "aggs": {
                                "items": {
                                    "children": {
                                        "type": "item"
                                    },
                                    "aggs": {
                                        "price": {
                                            "sum": {
                                                "field": "price"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Despite the query response listing matching results, the aggregation response doesn't match any items:

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "categories": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "category1",
                    "doc_count": 1,
                    "sub_categories": {
                        "doc_count": 3,
                        "sub_category_ids": {
                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                            "buckets": [
                                {
                                    "key": "subcat1",
                                    "doc_count": 1,
                                    "items": {
                                        "doc_count": 0,
                                        "price": {
                                            "value": 0
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "subcat2",
                                    "doc_count": 1,
                                    "items": {
                                        "doc_count": 0,
                                        "price": {
                                            "value": 0
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "subcat3",
                                    "doc_count": 1,
                                    "items": {
                                        "doc_count": 0,
                                        "price": {
                                            "value": 0
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
```

However, omitting the `sub_category_ids` aggregation does cause the items to appear and for prices to be summed at the level of the `categories` aggregation. I would expect including the `sub_category_ids` aggregation to simply change the level at which the prices are summed.

Am I misunderstanding how the aggregation is evaluated, and if so how could I modify it to display the summed prices for each sub-category?

Comment: For the benefit of others, @ChintanShah25 created [this related issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15413) in the ES repo.

Comment: I opened an issue as @Val said, If it is an urgent issue you might want to downgrade to `1.7` as your query is working with `ES 1.7`,  I am facing similar issue in my project, [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072977/children-aggregation-broken-in-elasticsearch-2-1) also highlights the same problem

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Good to know that a bug might be the cause. I'll keep an eye on the issue.

Comment: The [following PR](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/15457) will solve the issue and be available in ES 2.1.2.

Comment: Either of you, if you'd like, feel free to post the issue/PR as an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened an issue [#15413](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15413), regarding `children aggregation` as I and other folks were facing similar issues in `ES 2.0`

Apparently the problem according to ES developer @martijnvg was that

> The children agg makes an assumption (that all segments are being seen by children agg) that was true in 1.x but not in 2.x

[PR #15457](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/15457) fixed this issue, again from @martijnvg

> Before we only evaluated segments that yielded matches in parent aggs, which caused us to miss to evaluate child docs in segments we didn't have parent matches for.
>
> The fix for this is stop remember in what segments we have matches for
>   and simply evaluate all segments. This makes the code simpler and we
>   can still quickly see if a segment doesn't hold child docs like we did
>   before

This pull request has been merged and it has also been **back ported** to the `2.x, 2.1 and 2.0 branches`.

Comment: The fix has been released and is [available in 2.0.2 and 2.1.1](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-2-1-0-and-2-0-1-and-1-7-4-released)